# Wget Not Downloading Every Folder

Tags: ftp, directory, wget

Hey, I have bash script running a wget command to get a directory:

```
wget -r -nH --cut-dirs=5 "ftp://$USER:$PASS@stumpyinc.com/subdomains/cydia/httpdocs/theme/themes/$theme_root"
```

And what it's supposed to do is download a folder structure that looks like this:

```
$theme_root/Library/Themes/$theme_name.theme/Icons
```

For some reason, it wont download any folder that's inside of the `$theme_name.theme` folder. There's also a UIImages folder in there that's not showing up, although files that are in that folder are being downloaded. Does anyone notice anything that I might have done wrong? Thanks in advance!

EDIT
if you add `--level=inf` it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wget's default directory retrieval depth is 5 directories as per the [wget manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Retrieval-Options.html). If the files you are trying to get are deeper than that from your starting position, it will not go down there. You can try giving a larger `--level` option or as your edit `--level=inf`.